# How to mock a provider

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

My Angular 1.3 application is using the [angular-translate library](http://angular-translate.github.io/). In my Karma tests I'm attempting to mock the `$translate` provider with a Mock object I have created.

The mock object is called `MockTranslate` and it belongs to the `myMocks` module. I'm not including the source for `MockTranslate` in the question as it's not relevant to the question.

The subject of my test is a controller and I can quite easily mock `$translate` using the following:

```
module('myMocks');
inject(function($controller, MockTranslate) {                                                                                              
  $controller("MyController", {                                                                                                           
    $translate: MockTranslate.create(translations);                                                                                        
  });                                                                                                                                      
});
```

The above mocking works, however my preference would be to mock the provider using the `angular.mock.module` with something like:

```
module('myMocks');
module("myModule", function($provide) {                                                                                                    
  $provide.provider("$translate", function(MockTranslate) {                                                                              
    return MockTranslate.create(translations);                                                                                      
  });                                                                                                                                      
});
```

But I get the following error when I run my tests:

`Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module function ($provide) due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: MockTranslate`

How do I mock a provider using `angular.mock.module`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If I understood the task correctly then here is a working example:

```js
angular.module('translateApp', [])
    .controller('translateCtrl', function ($scope, $translate) {
        $scope.translate = function(message) {
            return $translate.translate(message);
        };
    })
    .provider({
        $translate: function() {
            this.$get = function () {
                return {
                    translate: function (msg) {
                        return 'OriginalTranslate: ' + msg;
                    }
                };
            };
        }
    });

describe('Translate Controller Test', function() {
    var mockScope;
    var mockTranslate;

    beforeEach(module('translateApp', function($provide) {
        $provide.provider('MockTranslate', function() {
            this.$get = function () {
                return {
                    translate: function (msg) {
                        return 'MockTranslate: ' + msg;
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        $provide.provider('$translate', function() {
            this.$get = function (MockTranslate) {
                return {
                    translate: function (msg) {
                        return MockTranslate.translate(msg);
                    }
                };
            }
        });
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $translate) {
        mockScope = $rootScope.$new();
        mockTranslate = $translate;

        $controller('translateCtrl', {
            $scope: mockScope,
            $translate: mockTranslate
        });
    }));

    it('Translates messages', function () {
        expect(mockScope.translate('cool message')).toEqual('MockTranslate: cool message');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @sbedulin you helped me realise that the provider needed to implement a `$get` function.

Comment: @b73 welcome! Note that dependencies go into `$get` function as well. Would be great if you marked the answer as helpful :)

Comment: Thanks @sbedulin, yes you also brought to my attention that the dependencies go in the `$get` function ;) I added a separate answer as it shows the exact solution I went with.

Comment: Does this have to be a mock service? Can't we just stub `<h1>{{ 'TEST' | translate }}</h1>` and run $scope.$apply with $translate.use?

Comment: The whole idea was to mock a service (any service, not just translate). Can you please provide a whole code example with `h1` and `scope.$apply`?